# Rewriting Adminhtml Block - To add custom validation to coupons (shopping cart rule)

Tags: overrides, shopping-cart-price-rules, magento-1.4

I have extended the Block `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Promo_Quote_Edit_Tab_Main` and added the changed code in the new class `Acer_Coupon_Block_Adminhtml_Promo_Quote_Edit_Tab_Main`. For some reason, the Block override does not work.

> \app\etc\modules\Acer_Coupon.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
     <modules>
     <Acer_Coupon>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Acer_Coupon>
    </modules>
</config>
```

> \app\code\local\Acer\Coupon\etc\config.xml:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Acer_Coupon>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        <Acer_Coupon>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <promo_quote_edit_tab_main>Acer_Coupon_Block_Adminhtml_Promo_Quote_Edit_Tab_Main</promo_quote_edit_tab_main>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

> \app\code\local\Acer\Coupon\Block\Adminhtml\Promo\Quote\Edit\Tab\Main.php:

```
<?php
class Acer_Coupon_Block_Adminhtml_Promo_Quote_Edit_Tab_Main extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Promo_Quote_Edit_Tab_Main
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $model = Mage::registry('current_promo_quote_rule');

        //$form = new Varien_Data_Form(array('id' => 'edit_form1', 'action' => $this->getData('action'), 'method' => 'post'));
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();

        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('rule_');

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('General Information')));

        if ($model->getId()) {
            $fieldset->addField('rule_id', 'hidden', array(
                'name' => 'rule_id',
            ));
        }

        $fieldset->addField('product_ids', 'hidden', array(
            'name' => 'product_ids',
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('name', 'text', array(
            'name' => 'name',
            'label' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Rule Name'),
            'title' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Rule Name'),
            'required' => true,
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('description', 'textarea', array(
            'name' => 'description',
            'label' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Description'),
            'title' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Description'),
            'style' => 'width: 98%; height: 100px;',
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('is_active', 'select', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Status'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Status'),
            'name'      => 'is_active',
            'required' => true,
            'options'    => array(
                '1' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Active'),
                '0' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Inactive'),
            ),
        ));
        if (!$model->getId()) {
            $model->setData('is_active', '1');
        }


        if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
            $fieldset->addField('website_ids', 'multiselect', array(
                'name'      => 'website_ids[]',
                'label'     => Mage::helper('catalogrule')->__('Websites'),
                'title'     => Mage::helper('catalogrule')->__('Websites'),
                'required'  => true,
                'values'    => Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_config_source_website')->toOptionArray(),
            ));
        }
        else {
            $fieldset->addField('website_ids', 'hidden', array(
                'name'      => 'website_ids[]',
                'value'     => Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getWebsiteId()
            ));
            $model->setWebsiteIds(Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getWebsiteId());
        }

        $customerGroups = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/group_collection')
            ->load()->toOptionArray();

        $found = false;
        foreach ($customerGroups as $group) {
            if ($group['value']==0) {
                $found = true;
            }
        }
        if (!$found) {
            array_unshift($customerGroups, array('value'=>0, 'label'=>Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('NOT LOGGED IN')));
        }

        $fieldset->addField('customer_group_ids', 'multiselect', array(
            'name'      => 'customer_group_ids[]',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Customer Groups'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Customer Groups'),
            'required'  => true,
            'values'    => $customerGroups,
        ));

        $couponTypeFiled = $fieldset->addField('coupon_type', 'select', array(
            'name'       => 'coupon_type',
            'label'      => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Coupon'),
            'required'   => true,
            'options'    => Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->getCouponTypes(),
        ));

        $couponCodeFiled = $fieldset->addField('coupon_code', 'text', array(
            'name' => 'coupon_code',
            'class' => 'validate-coupon-code',
            'label' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Extended Coupon Code'),
            'required' => true,
        ));

        $usesPerCouponFiled = $fieldset->addField('uses_per_coupon', 'text', array(
            'name' => 'uses_per_coupon',
            'label' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Uses per Coupon'),
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('uses_per_customer', 'text', array(
            'name' => 'uses_per_customer',
            'label' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Uses per Customer'),
        ));

        $dateFormatIso = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT);
        $fieldset->addField('from_date', 'date', array(
            'name'   => 'from_date',
            'label'  => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('From Date'),
            'title'  => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('From Date'),
            'image'  => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
            'input_format' => Varien_Date::DATE_INTERNAL_FORMAT,
            'format'       => $dateFormatIso
        ));
        $fieldset->addField('to_date', 'date', array(
            'name'   => 'to_date',
            'label'  => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('To Date'),
            'title'  => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('To Date'),
            'image'  => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
            'input_format' => Varien_Date::DATE_INTERNAL_FORMAT,
            'format'       => $dateFormatIso
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('sort_order', 'text', array(
            'name' => 'sort_order',
            'label' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Priority'),
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('is_rss', 'select', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Public In RSS Feed'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Public In RSS Feed'),
            'name'      => 'is_rss',
            'options'   => array(
                '1' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Yes'),
                '0' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('No'),
            ),
        ));

        if(!$model->getId()){
            //set the default value for is_rss feed to yes for new promotion
            $model->setIsRss(1);
        }

        $form->setValues($model->getData());

        if ($model->isReadonly()) {
            foreach ($fieldset->getElements() as $element) {
                $element->setReadonly(true, true);
            }
        }

        //$form->setUseContainer(true);

        $this->setForm($form);

        // field dependencies
        $this->setChild('form_after', $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_form_element_dependence')
            ->addFieldMap($couponTypeFiled->getHtmlId(), $couponTypeFiled->getName())
            ->addFieldMap($couponCodeFiled->getHtmlId(), $couponCodeFiled->getName())
            ->addFieldMap($usesPerCouponFiled->getHtmlId(), $usesPerCouponFiled->getName())
            ->addFieldDependence(
                $couponCodeFiled->getName(),
                $couponTypeFiled->getName(),
                Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::COUPON_TYPE_SPECIFIC)
            ->addFieldDependence(
                $usesPerCouponFiled->getName(),
                $couponTypeFiled->getName(),
                Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::COUPON_TYPE_SPECIFIC)
        );

        Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_promo_quote_edit_tab_main_prepare_form', array('form' => $form));

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

I've changed the label of coupon code to "Extended Coupon code" in above file. But it still shows the label as "Coupon code" so it is certain that something is wrong in my procedure.

I've searched through many different links and tried several approaches like putting **Block** inside **Adminhtml** and vice-versa, but nothing worked.

I have developed a good habit of clearing cache after every change(mostly xml files).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you put a `die();` at the top of Acer_Coupon_Block_Adminhtml_Promo_Quote_Edit_Tab_Main::_prepareForm() to see if your rewrite is been execute ... the issue seem to be the fact that your return `parent::_prepareForm();`

Comment: putting "die();" at the first did not make any difference.. so basically the rewrite is not executed

Comment: Can you check to see if the module is enable? Did you clear cache?

Comment: Yes, the module is enabled. just re-confirmed it from System->configuration->Advanced. And yes, I cleared Cache before trying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your rewrite `return parent::_prepareForm();` which is class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Promo_Quote_Edit_Tab_Main` you will need to rewrite it parent class.

In \app\code\local\Acer\Coupon\Block\Adminhtml\Promo\Quote\Edit\Tab\Main.php:

```
class Acer_Coupon_Block_Adminhtml_Promo_Quote_Edit_Tab_Main
extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
{
  .....
```

Then copy all the content of Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Promo_Quote_Edit_Tab_Main and then make your changes

Comment: Today, I tried your suggestion, but it still does not work. So, it means somehow the rewrite fails

Comment: As you stated the rewrite is not executing. So we need to figure that out first

Comment: Good news is after removing "<modules> tag from the config.xml, rewrite worked :)

Comment: and once rewriting worked, I followed this answer and everything works great :) 
can you pls edit your answer and mention about modules tag in config,xml? so that I can accept your answer

Comment: The "modules" tag in the config shouldn't affect anyting

Comment: yes it is affecting.. If I keep it again and clear cache. The rewrite won't work. Anyway, i'm happy that finally we could resolve it.. any idea why it won't work with modules tag?

Comment: Something else is causing that issue, which should be unrelating to issue listed above.

Comment: Great .Your suggestion works.

Answer (score 1):

Following [Renon Stewart's answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/82909), you could also change the return call to:

```
return $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_form')->_prepareForm();
```

Instead of rewriting the parent class.