# Magento Promotion Rules

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to add new dropdown after status tex box where can i do
[image]

Comment: Please provide more information what exactly want to do?

Comment: You asking for catalog price rule or shopping cart price rules?

Comment: extend `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Promo/Quote/Edit/Tab/Main.php`

Comment: thanx gopal patel

Comment: how can i override this 
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Promo_Quote_Edit_Tab_Main
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
    implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
{

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/82904/rewriting-adminhtml-block-to-add-custom-validation-to-coupons-shopping-cart-r

Comment: how add data in database i mean in which table i save this